# script en bash para almacenar resultado de una query de Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, bash

Espero que alguno me podáis ayudar.

Necesito crear un script en bash que se conecte a una Mongodb:

```
mongo --host mongodb://IP:PORT,IP:PORT/admin?replicaSet=rs0 -u admin -p passadmin
```

seleccione la db:

```
use Data
```

y lance la consulta:

```
db.OPERATIONS.find({"Description":"OK."}).count()
```

de la última hora, creo que sería algo así:

```
{$lte: new Date().getTime()-(1*60)}
```

y lo guarde en un fichero p.ej:

```
/tmp/count.log con el timestamp de la consulta.
```

Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: intentastes con [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)? 
 seria algo como `mongoexport -d Data -c OPERATIONS --csv --query {$lte: new Date().getTime()-(1*60)} --out /ymp/count.log`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta JackNavaRow. La consulta no devuelve resultados. Creo que el filtro de tiempo, {$lte: new Date().getTime()-(1*60)}  no es correcto. Lanzaré una nueva consulta y retomaré esta cuando funcione. Gracias!

Comment: la idea es el output la consulta puedes escribir lo que quieras